# Заполнение div столькими элементами, каково их количество указано в массиве

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, dom, for

У меня не получается правильно отобразить количество плюсов в каждом диве. Исходя из массива, в первом должно быть 3 плюса, во втором 5, а в последнем один.

```js
    let body = document.getElementById('body');
    let data = [
        {count: 3},
        {count: 5},
        {count: 1},
    ];
    body.innerHTML = '<div></div><br><div></div><br><div></div>';
    let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < data[i]['count']; k++) {
                divs[j].innerHTML += '+';
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас лишний цикл, сейчас вы в каждый div добавляете сначала 3 плюса, потом 5 и потом 1, отсюда и получается в каждом по 9

```js
let body = document.getElementById('body');
let data = [
  {count: 3},
  {count: 5},
  {count: 1},
];
body.innerHTML = '<div></div><br><div></div><br><div></div>';
let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < data[i]['count']; k++) {
    divs[i].innerHTML += '+';
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```